# Instalar hybridauth a un proyecto que ya se encuentra montado en un servidor

Tags: php, servidor, redes-sociales

Tengo un proyecto de forma local e instalé `hybridauth` para hacer inicio de sesión con redes sociales, pero ahora lo subí a un servidor de prueba y mi problema es que no sé cómo instalar `hybridauth` al proyecto que ya se encuentra subido.

De forma local instalé composer para instalar la librería de hybridauth, me fui a la terminal e hice referencia a la ubicación de mi proyecto, después puse este comando para instalar hybridauth: `composer require hybridauth/hybridauth`